# How is it possible to find user's keyboard layout change method?

Tags: keyboard-layout, autohotkey

I've written an AutoHotKey script which changes keyboard layout by pressing CapsLock. 
Pressing CapsLock simply emulates "LeftAlt down + Left Shift + LeftAlt Up" combination. 
It's obvious, that my program won't work if Control+Shift is set to keyboard layout change method. 
I've tried searching over registry, but there's no useful information in HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/Keyboard Layout(s).
So, is it possible somehow to find out user's method to change layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Keyboard layout toggle

The information you're looking for is stored in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Toggle
```

The key sequence is determined by the `Layout Hotkey` value:

```
1 = Left Alt + Shift
2 = Ctrl + Shift
3 = Not assigned
4 = Grave accent
```

When the value is missing, that means the default setting is being used (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

### References

- [Hotkey](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976564.aspx)

Comment: Well, I have no "Layout Hotkey" value there. Moreover, there're no values:(

Comment: @Kondra007 When the values are missing that means the default settings are being used (i.e. Left Alt + Shift to switch the input language, and Ctrl + Shift to switch the keyboard layout).

Comment: @Kondra007 You're welcome. Keep in mind the user might use the **Not assigned** option, in which case there's not hotkey you can emulate. If that's an issue, you'll need to consider a different approach.