# How to assign a custom key for switching keyboard input languages in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

How one can assign a custom key (e.g. Scroll Lock) for switching keyboard input languages in Windows 7? (Apart from Ctrl-Shift or Alt-Shift). Preferably not using third party programs. Maybe by changing some settings in registry?

Comment: Windows only allows [certain key sequences](http://superuser.com/questions/793406/how-is-it-possible-to-find-users-keyboard-layout-change-method) and whether you tweak the registry directly or not, it doesn't matter. You'll have to resort to third-party programs to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that you won't find a way to do this natively within windows, but Autohotkey and Autoit both make it very easy:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

In Autohotkey this should work:
    `ScrollLock::Send {alt down}{lshift}{alt up}`